# why data is varying from sqlite database to django template(tab spaces are removed)?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm fetching data from Sqlite database into django template varaibles to print, but output is different from db to variable output( tab spaces and normal space are removed).
Here is template code:

```
    {% for item in xxx.xxx.all %}
        {{ item.value }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I create an file called `test.html` with the following text

```
column1    column2    column3
   1          2          3
```

And then open it up in my browser. I see

```
column1 column2 column3 0 1 2
```

That is because a browser rendering HTML doesn't care about whitespace. It strips most of it out. I have to use formatting tags. Wrapping my example in `<pre>` tags is enough to get the desired result.

```
</pre>
column1    column2    column3
   1          2          3
</pre>
```

Now, this might not actually be your problem. It's possible you are just templating a plain text file. But it's a bit tricky to tell from your question. Do you actually have 9 rows in your db table containing

```
column1\tcolumn2\tcolumn3
0\t0\t0
1\t0\t0
2\t0\t0
3\t0\t0
4\t0\t0
5\t0\t0
6\t0\t0
7\t0\t0
8\t0\t0
9\t0\t0
```

By that I mean does the data ACTUALLY contain tab characters or is sqlite just adding tabs when it displays the data? Because if it is the latter you'll have to add those tab stops/spaces in yourself in the template.

What you should do is, in a python terminal, run your query and then do a `print repr(item.value)`. That will show you the string literal representation of the data you are working with.

Comment: yes,the original data contains tab characters. I'm fetching all the data into variable but while printing it spaces are getting removed! and new line is working fine!

Comment: I'm still not clear what transformations or formats you are moving your data through. Any one of which might be causing this to happen. You'll have to be explicit.

Comment: <pre> tag is working fine, but in some cases result is different!  thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: If you want column data in a table in HTML you'll have to use an actual table... You would split each row on `\t` and then have another inner loop which adds `<td>{{ item }}</td>` tags to each cell.